How to use Epstein-Zin model to show the preference for early/late resolution?
Consider the Epstein-Zin utility function:
$$
U_t=\left\{\left(1-\beta\right)c_t^\rho+\beta \left[E_t \left(U_{t+1}^\alpha\right)\right]^\frac{\rho}{\alpha}\right\}^{\frac{1}{\rho}}.
$$ To simplify the algebra, I modified it to
$$
U_t=\left\{c_t^\rho+\beta \left[E_t \left(U_{t+1}^\alpha\right)\right]^\frac{\rho}{\alpha}\right\}^{\frac{1}{\rho}}.
$$ Let $V_t=U_t^\rho$, we have
$$
V_t=c_t^\rho+\beta\left[E_t\left(V_{t+1}^{\frac{1}{\gamma}}\right)\right]^\gamma
$$ where $\gamma=\frac{\rho}{\alpha}$. To further simplify, I let $\beta=1$, so
$$
V_t=c_t^\rho+\left[E_t\left(V_{t+1}^{\frac{1}{\gamma}}\right)\right]^\gamma.
$$ If $\gamma>1$, then the decision maker should prefer early resolution.
The formal proof in Kreps and Porteus (1978) and Epstein and Zin (1989) are too technical for me. I tried to get a sense of it through a simple example, but failed. Consider a specific consumption lottery: $c_0=c_1=c_3=\cdots=0$ and $c_2$ is a random variable. Consider the following two cases.
The first is ``early resolution,'' that is, in period 1, the decision maker knows the value of $c_2$. So
$$
E_1\left(V_2^{\frac{1}{\gamma}}\right)=V_2^{\frac{1}{\gamma}}
$$ and thus
$$
V_1=V_2.
$$ Then
$$
V_0=\left[E_0\left(V_1^{\frac{1}{\gamma}}\right)\right]^\gamma=\left[E\left(V_2^{\frac{1}{\gamma}}\right)\right]^\gamma.
$$
The second is ``late resolution,'' that is, the decision maker does not know the value of $c_2$ until period 2. So
$$
V_1=\left[E_1\left(V_2^{\frac{1}{\gamma}}\right)\right]^\gamma
$$ and
$$
V_0=\left[E_0\left(V_1^{\frac{1}{\gamma}}\right)\right]^\gamma=\left[\left(V_1^{\frac{1}{\gamma}}\right)\right]^\gamma=V_1=\left[E_1\left(V_2^{\frac{1}{\gamma}}\right)\right]^\gamma.
$$
In sum, $V_0$ in both cases are the same, which should be wrong. Could you please help me to figure out my mistake? Thank you very much!
